# Get Total Occurrence of Data from a Table in php

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get the total number of `serviceType` column based on the sample report below. I need to know the query that can give me the result. Based on the report, I am expected to get 8. But I am only getting 2.

What I did is to first get the distinct `fltno`, and next to count the total `id`’s for a particular fltno, and finally sum it up. However, i am still not getting the result. Please, someone should help me with the query that i can best use.
Based on report below,

```
AFMG 001 has 2A'S = 1 service, AFMG 002 has 2A's = 1 service,AFMG 003 has 3B'S = 1 service, AFMG 004 has 2B's  = 1 service, AFMG 005 has 2A'S = 1 service,AFMG 006 has 2A'S = 1 service, AFMG 009 has  2A'S = 1 service,AFMG  010 has 2A'S = 1 service
```

Hence total services = 8

How can I get this via query using PHP.  Please note that one fltno might have more than one servicetype like `AFMG 001` can still have  `3B'S` and that should be counted as 1 service as well.

```
<?php 
    //get distinct fltno
$d4 = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link,"SELECT DISTINCT(fltno)AS flt FROM tab_mrptrans WHERE loc='".$rw['loc']."'"));
$sc=0;
//get no of nextSvr for particular fltno
$q1 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT count(id)AS ids FROM tab_name WHERE loc='".$rw['loc']."' AND fltno='$d4['flt']");
while($d3 = mysqli_fetch_array($q1)){
$sc+=$d3['ids'];};?>
```

[image]

Comment: @Nemgathos, Please do you know the answer to my question? Please help if you can.

Comment: So to understand better you want to count column serviceType , only the unique values. so a combination of distinct and count right?

Comment: @pr1nc3: Exactly, count the serviceType Column for the unique values for a paticular fltno column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

So after you get the array of `fltno` you need to loop around it

```
$counter=0;
foreach($array as $row) {
    $d4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, " SELECT count(DISTINCT serviceType) AS count FROM my_table WHERE fltno='{$row['fltno']}'"));
      $counter=$counter+$d4['count'];
}

echo $counter;
```

The query as we tested before returns the distinct number for 1 fltno, which will be stored in a variable `$counter`. This value is increased with the output of every query (which is a number). At the end will `echo` you the sum of serviceTypes. Modify your `array` name to make it work. I just used the name $array for example.

Comment: let me try this .

Comment: it returns zero(0).I want it to return it for each distinct fltno as well, then sum it up.

Comment: Sorry, i made mistake earlier not changing some parameters. When i corrected that, it shows 1, when i removed the WHERE clause, it returns 2.

Comment: Then it is working right. I only see A and B in the array.  
So for all it counts 2 unique and for a fltno can count from 1 to 2

Comment: Take a look at the analysis above, for further understanding. If i know it, I will not post it as questions. All that is required is to calculate the total number of servicetype for all the fltno. one fltno can have 3 distinct services, and another one might have 2 distinct servicetype.

Comment: It is in array, now looping over it, seems to be the issue. When i attempt to do that, it loops continuously.

Comment: Yes, if you look at the column`nextSvr` that is the one that shows the sequence, a particular fltno has to go through. fltno AFMG 001 can do 3A with  `nextSvr` as 7, the same can do another with `nextSvr` as 8

Comment: Pls, did you try the above and it works for you?, As this is still not working.

Comment: Now it should work. Tested it as well. Careful with the array field you are inserting in the where clause.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I will check this as done. Now, what if i want to use the column `nextSvr` and say one fltno has 2A'S for nextsvr  as 6, 2B'S for another nextsvr as 7 and another 2A'S  for nextSvr as 8.Will this code still work?

Comment: This code for sure will get you started as you get the unique values and map them. You will need to expand it but it will be easy i guess. Just stick to the "mindset" of those queries and how they work and you will be fine to create your new one. If not SO will be here to help resolve your issues. But first give it a try.